# NSMutableArray running into problems with __NSArrayI removeObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsarray, variable-assignment, retain

I've already looked at the other SO discussions but can't seem to find an answer. I'm getting this answer after basically the following code:

1) In the class that owns the AwesomeMenu, I am making an NSMutableArray of AwesomeMenuItems, which is required to initialize the AwesomeMenu:

```
NSMutableArray *menus = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
[menus addObject:starMenuItem1];
[menus addObject:starMenuItem2];
[menus addObject:starMenuItem3];
[menus addObject:starMenuItem4];
[menus addObject:starMenuItem5];

AwesomeMenu *menu = [[[AwesomeMenu alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds menus:menus view:self.view] autorelease];
```

2) In AwesomeMenu.h, I have the array declared in the interface like so:

```
NSMutableArray *_menusArray;
```

And I've made a property for the array:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *menusArray;
```

and it is synthesized:

```
@synthesize menusArray = _menusArray;
```

3) In the initWithFrame: menus: view: , I assign the menus parameter like so:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame menus:(NSMutableArray *)aMenusArray view:(UIView*)gView
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    // ... some code
    self.menusArray = aMenusArray; // BREAKPOINT HERE.
    // ... some more code
}
```

4) I put a breakpoint at the assignment and here is what happens. Immediately before that line is run, I check my self.menusArray and it is: (NSMutableArray *)0x00000000 0 Objects

I step over the line and it becomes:
(__NSArrayI *) 0x06045070 5 objects.

While this is the correct number of objects, it is no longer a NSMutableArray which runs me into problems later!

What is happening and how can I stop it from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the declaration of the following in your `AwesomeMenu.h` file. Make sure that you change the the `NSArray` to `NSMutableArray` there as well. That also could cause this issue.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame menus:(NSMutableArray *)aMenusArray view:(UIView*)gView;
```

**Update:**
Just a note. In init method always use the following after allocating memory for self.

```
if (self) {
   //code goes here
}
```

**Update2:**
Also change `self.menusArray = aMenusArray;` to `_menusArray = [aMenusArray retain]`

As per apple documentation you are not supposed to use `self.param` in `init` and `dealloc` method since it is in the process of memory allocation/destruction which is not complete yet.

Comment: It is declared as a mutable array in the header file. No problems there.

Thanks for the tip, adding it.

Comment: What about the this line in your .h file - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame menus:(NSMutableArray *)aMenusArray view:(UIView*)gView; Does it have NSMutableArray or NSArray in it? Can you please post that line from your .h file.

Comment: - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame menus:(NSMutableArray *)aMenusArray view:(UIView*) gView;

This looks right, right? This is the line from the .h file, directly pasted.

Comment: The asterisks are removed in the comments. The NSMutableArray and the UIView are pointers.

Comment: That looks fine for me. So are you using ARC? If not can you change your strong keyword to retain and see what happens? Other than that I dont see anything wrong with your code here.

Comment: I am not using ARC. Sorry, what is the strong keyword?

Comment: Strong is a keyword equivalent of retain when using ARC. I can see that in this example you are already using retain. So please ignore that comment. Probably you need to post some more code from your class. From the above code, everything looks fine.

Comment: Try changing self.menusArray = aMenusArray; to _menusArray = [aMenusArray retain]; Not sure whether that will resolve your issue though.

Comment: Whoa! That worked! Why do you think that that was the reason? Please update your answer to reflect your last comment because, yeah, that worked. :)

Comment: As per apple documentation you are not supposed to use self.property in init and dealloc method since it is in the process of memory allocation/destruction which is not complete yet. I am not sure if that is related to this behavior in anyway.

Comment: That would be a problem if I had subclasses of this - but I do not. So I do not think there would be any memory conflicts here. I realize it shouldn't happen. But the fact that this problem exists, even when I am not subclassing this, suggests that I am corrupting my memory somewhere.

Comment: In that case, whatever was the issue, I can assure you that it was not in the code posted above. Because I have used similar implementations and it always worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

__NSArrayI it's inmutable array, you are passing to initWithFrame method NSArray, not NSMutable array

Solution:

```
self.menusArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:aMenusArray]; // BREAKPOINT HERE.
```

Comment: I checked the aMenusArray I'm passing in. It is a Mutable Array prior to and after assignment. It is only the self.menusArray that somehow turns into the __NSArrayI type. It makes no sense to me.

Comment: Also, to confirm, I tried the above and it did not work for me.

Comment: I would propose removeObjectAtIndex, however I cannot because I'm stuck with a __NSArrayI type instead of a NSMutableArray. Do you understand that I am dealing with an immutable array when I expect it to be mutable?

Comment: i understand, but i have a lack of code and can't fully figure out. I asked you for more code to understand it. So, code this remove items will help

Comment: It's not my function - it belongs to NSMutableArray. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: No, I am not. I am only trying to add items. But I cannot add items because somehow my mutable array is being turned into an immutable array at some point. I do not know what is causing this.

Comment: i think my first tip should help. Try to output a class name to console after assigment. NSLOG(@"%@", [[self.menusArray class] description]);